How to duplicate records in pandas dataframe based on column values
I have created a pandas dataframe as follows:
ds = {'col1' : ["A","B"], 'probability' : [0.3, 0.6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)   
  col1  probability
0    A   0.3
1    B   0.6

I need to create a new dataframe which duplicates each row and assign to the duplicated record a probability needed to sum up to 1.
From the example above:

I need to duplicate record 0 such that A gets a probability of 0.3 (so it keeps what's already in there) and the duplicated record gets a probability of 0.7 (0.3 + 0.7 = 1)
I need to duplicate record 1 such that B gets a probability of 0.6 (so it keeps what's already in there) and the duplicated record gets a probability of 0.4 (0.6 + 0.4 = 1)

The resulting dataframe looks like this:
  col1  probability
0    A          0.3
1    A          0.7
2    B          0.6
3    B          0.4

Can anyone help me doing it in pandas, please?

You can use this:
df = pd.concat([df, df.assign(probability=1 - df["probability"])], ignore_index=True)

  col1  probability
0    A          0.3
1    B          0.6
2    A          0.7
3    B          0.4


A possible solution, which first creates a second dataframe with col1 and 1-probability. Then, it vertically concatenates the second dataframe to the original one, and sorts by col1:
pd.concat([
    df, 
    pd.DataFrame(zip(df['col1'], 1-df['probability']), columns=df.columns)])
.sort_values('col1')


Alternatively (this might be preferred), as @mozway suggests in a comment below:
(pd.concat([
    df, 
    pd.DataFrame({'col1': df['col1'], 'probability': 1-df['probability']})])
 .sort_values('col1'))


Another approach, using list comprehension and numpy:
pd.DataFrame(
    np.vstack([np.array([[x, y], [x, 1-y]]) 
               for x, y in zip(df['col1'], df['probability'])]), 
    columns=df.columns)


Output:
  col1  probability
0    A          0.3
0    A          0.7
1    B          0.6
1    B          0.4


pd.DataFrame({'col1': df['col1'], 'probability': 1-df['probability']}) might be preferred (this keeps the original Series objects and should be more efficient than zip) ;)

Indeed, @mozway. Thanks!
